# How to run multiple instances of this command dd

Tags: linux, unix, command

I want to run this command multiple times but im not sure how to do it.
It has to be a single command. what this command does is it pushes my cpu cores to 
%100

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

Its for an assignment. please help if you can 
thank you

This is what in the assignment says. Maybe it can be helpfull to figure it out

> "Figure out how to run multiple instances of the command dd
>   if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null at the same time. You could also use the
>   command sum /dev/zero. You should run one instance per CPU core, so as
>   to push CPU utilization to 100% on all of the CPU cores in your
>   virtual machine. You should be able to launch all of the instances by
>   running a single command or pipeline as a regular user "

so far i tried doing

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | xargs -p2
```

but that doesn't do the job right

Comment: There are other ways to push your cores to 100% but if you want to do this, simply call `dd` with an `&` at the end `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
&` and repeat that how many ever times you want.

Comment: i cant do that. he said i can only launch all of the instances by running a single command or pipeline as a regular user

Comment: If you have `GNU Parallel` you can launch multiple instances of your command with it.

Comment: You can put multiple invocations in a single line using `&&` to separate them.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim - That's just wrong. `&&` is logical `AND`. The succeeding commands won't run until the previous command completes successfully. Since the command will never end, then the rest of the commands won't run. Hence, you'll only be running the first command, ever.

Comment: I'm not sure whats a GNU parallel. I'm just using vm for my linux class. still learning these stuff.
This is what says in the assignment 
"Figure out how to run multiple instances of the command dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null at the same time. You could also use the command sum /dev/zero. You should run one instance per CPU core, so as to push CPU utilization to 100% on all of the CPU cores in your virtual machine. You should be able to launch all of the instances by running a single command or pipeline as a regular user"

Comment: @alvits Your're right. I meant `&`. It was s typo.

Comment: This should fix your attempt with `xargs`. Try `printf "zero\nzero\nzero\nzero\n" | xargs -I{} -P4 dd if=/dev/{} of=/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment is probably already due and over. But for future readers, here's a single line solution.

```
perl -e 'print "/dev/zero\n" x'$(nproc --all) | xargs -n 1 -P $(nproc --all) -I{} dd if={} of=/dev/null
```

How does this work? Let's dissect the pipeline.

`nproc --all` will return the number of cores in the system. Let's pretend your system has 4 cores.

`perl -e 'print "/dev/zero\n" x 4'` will print 4 lines of `/dev/zero`.

Output

```
/dev/zero
/dev/zero
/dev/zero
/dev/zero
```

The output of perl is then passed to `xargs`.

`-n 1` tells `xargs` to use only one argument at a time.

`-I {}` tells `xargs` that the argument shall replace the occurrences of {}

`-P 4` tells `xargs` to run as many as 4 instances of the command in parallel

A shorter version of the above command can be written like this:

```
perl -e 'print "if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null\n" x '$(nproc --all) | xargs -n2 -P0 dd
```

Comment: Thank you. Its not due till next week

Answer (score 1):

This will run 4 copies:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

But it is really not recommended as a solution for homework, as it looks as if you do not understand what | does. Here nothing is being sent through the pipe. It has the advantage that it is easy to stop with a Ctrl-C.

If the goal is simply to increase carbon emissions then this is shorter:

```
 burnP6 | burnP6 | burnP6 | burnP6
```

If you have GNU Parallel:

```
yes /dev/zero | parallel dd if={} of=/dev/null
yes | parallel burnP6
```

GNU Parallel starts by default 1 job per CPU core, and thus it only reads that many arguments from `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways.. for example repeating the command four times:

command & ; command & ; command & ; command &

..or in a more systematic way:

```
for i in {1..4}
do
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
done
```

Comment: cant use scripting

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try my home made parallel data transfer tool [pdd](https://github.com/Juan-Cortez3/pdd). This tool spawns several threads and each of the threads is bond to a CPU core.